# How to Disable HTTPS in Nginx DaemonSet Installed via Helm?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install Ngnix Ingress using Helm as a DaemonSet using HostNetwork on K8S cluster. The object is to use it as a reverse proxy behind an AWS ALB which route external requests into the cluster. What I'm using is as follow (it's CDK, but should not matter):

```js
cluster.addChart('NginxIngress', {
  chart: 'nginx-ingress',
  repository: 'https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com',
  namespace: 'ingress-nginx',
  wait: true,
  values: {
    controller: {
      kind: 'DaemonSet',
      hostNetwork: true,
      daemonset: {
        useHostPort: true,
      },
      service: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    }
  }
});
```

When I describe the DaemonSet, I still see HTTPS ports:

```
  Containers:
   nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress:
    Image:       us.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.34.1
    Ports:       80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:  80/TCP, 443/TCP
```

I couldn't verify if it's actually listening to the port on the node since it's private (Is there any way to port-forward a node-port using `kubectl` like what we do for a service? Note that there's no Nginx service in my configuration.)
Is there anything I need to do? Again my objective is to have Nginx as a HTTP (not HTTPS) reverse proxy. Thanks.

**Update #1**
I already tried setting `controller.service.enableHttps=false`. It disables HTTPS on the service which I disabled altogether.
Also leaving `controller.daemonset.hostPorts.https` empty won't work, because, I think, if empty, it picks the default value.

Comment: Have you tried to add `controller.service.enableHttps: false` in the `config.yaml` that you use to install the helm chart?

Comment: Yup, it's for the service not the daemonset. And I disabled the service altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the daemonset template, there's this value map `controller.containerPort` containing two ports by default; `http` and `https`. You just need to remove the default `https` value from the map: `controller.containerPort.https=null`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress

You can use the boolean flag below to disable https

*if port 443 should be opened for service - default is true*

```
controller.service.enableHttps
```

Also there are other options for hostPort

*If controller.daemonset.useHostPort is true and this is non-empty, it sets the hostPort*

According to explanation you can unset this value to disable that port

```
controller.daemonset.hostPorts.https
```